# DBunitでエクセルからテーブルの値をとる方法について

Tags: java, spring, database, junit

DBunitで単体テストをしていますが、IDataSetのXlsDataSetメソッドでエクセルから表を取得したいのですが、エクセルファイルは認識するものの、「テーブル名.UNKNOWN.nullabaleUnknown」となりエクセルに記載しているテーブルの値を取得できません。どうすればよいかアドバイスいただけませんでしょうか。

エクリプス、Spring Boot、オラクルのDBを使用しています。

何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12174075387

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/10250

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/75958

Comment: 想定とは異なり質問文中のようなエラーが出るのはこのように記述したコードの箇所だ、というのを具体的に示すことは可能でしょうか。